# RegEx validating of a phone number with any given format

Tags: php, regex

I know that there a lot of questions for validating phone numbers here, but I didn't find an answer to my problem.

Using a web form I ask for mobile numbers, which are used to send a SMS verification codes (2FA). Therefore the numbers shall be formatted all the same way.

The phone numbers are being submitted as strings. Right now, I elimate everything that is not a digit with PHP preg_replace first.

```
$phonenumber = preg_replace("/\D/","",$phonenumber);
```

With a second rule I try to catch any given number format with

```
$phonenumber = preg_replace('/^(0049|00490|\+49|\+490|0)/i',"$2",$phonenumber)
```

How can I put both into just one Regular Expression?

My goal is to have all numbers in a format of 0049123456789 finally.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: oh, you're going to be in a world of pain. also: what does your "second rule" even mean?! `$2` would be the second match. the thing in parens is `$1`, there is no `$2`. also enjoy https://github.com/google/libphonenumber/blob/master/FALSEHOODS.md ... ultimately, you're probably already doomed regarding your goal ;o/ you probably should look for some library that syntactically validates and reformats the phone number.

Comment: This is not a clear [mcve]. We need a battery of input tests and your expected results from each test string.